# search in array where elements differ by 1

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Interview question: Given an array where any two consecutive elements differ in their values by 1

example:

```
vector<int> vec = { 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4,-3,-2,-1,0,1, 2, 1, 2, 3 };
            index==>0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 6, 7, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

The aim is to search an element  K in this array in less than O(n).

My attempt: 
start from index 0 . we can skip some indexes. Since elements differ by 1 and we need to search for k ,  lets insect elements and see a range in between which element could be found.

index = 0

The max value I can predict will be at a[idx + k] and min value at a[idx -k] as at each value differ by 1  .. however, this does not lead to anywhere

EDIT:
Code tried for suggestion given in an answer

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int closeS(vector<int> & vec, int search , int& hopsTaken)
{
    int idx = 0;
    while (idx < vec.size() && vec[idx] != search)
    {
        idx += abs (search - vec[idx]);

        ++hopsTaken;
    }

    if (idx < vec.size())
    {
        cout << idx <<"\n";
        return idx;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int hopsTaken = 0;
    vector<int> vec = { 1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,1,2,3 };
    cout << closeS(vec, 3, hopsTaken);  // , 0, vec.size() - 1)];
    cout << "  \n hopsTaken " << hopsTaken <<"  in array size" << vec.size() <<" for k = " << 3 <<"\n";
    int y;
    cin >> y;

    return 0;
}
```

Tried few items and it was always <= O(n/k)

Still searching for better as its still O(n)

Comment: You can use binary search approach to search an element.

Comment: Wont work as it will go up and down and have a lot of local minimas and local maximals

Comment: There will be multiple queries or just one?

Comment: Impossible. Say you have an array (0,1,0,1,...,0,1,2,1,0,...,1,0,1) and you need to search for 2. You don't know where in the array this 2 is and cannot possibly know without looking at at least N/2 elements.

Comment: *Still searching*. Good luck...

Comment: @n.m. O(n) is the worst case, it can be faster i believe. but multi-threading cheat can make it faster obviously.

Comment: you can look at first element and last element, if the difference is `n-1` you know that array is ordered and you can even tell the direction (increasing or decreasing order). best case would be `O(1)` if `K` is not in that range. you can do binary search. you can do the same for portion of the array. maybe divide and conquer can help. the challenge is to find local min/maxs.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary "is the worst case" Also the average case I believe, will be happy to see a counterexample. "it can be faster i believe" Nope, the worst case cannot be faster. "multi-threading cheat can make it faster obviously" There's no such thing as "multi-threading cheat". Unless you have an infinite number of CPUs that is. If you have 12 CPUs, O(n/12) is still O(n).

Comment: @n.m. you are right. it will be O(n) on average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin at the first index and jump by the difference to the searched Element:

Eg Search for 2: Begin at index 0

```
0, vec[0]=1,  2-1=1  => nextindex 0+1=1
1, vec[1]=0,  2-0=2  => 1+2=3
3, vec[3]=-2, 2--2=4 => 3+4=7
7, vec[7]=-2, 2--2=4 => 7+4=11
11, vec[11]=2
```

Eg Search for 3: Begin at index 0

```
0, vec[0]=1,  3-1=2  => 0+2=2
2, vec[2]=-1, 3--1=4 => 2+4=6
6, vec[6]=-3, 3--3=6 => 6+6=12
12, vec[12]=1, 3-1=2  => 12+2=14
14, vec[11]=3
```

Comment: What is the time complexity for your algo?

Comment: it sys ... Can you please explain . The complexity seems to be O(n/k)

Comment: As the difference is always 1 between the elements the next index to check is the difference between k adn the current value. Sorry im not able to determin the complexity right now, this was a spontanous post, solving the problem

Comment: The time complexity is O(n), for example, if k = 4, and array is [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,...] -> the algo with jumping from 0, 2, 4, 6 ... which is n/2 until the end of the array.

Comment: Tried his approach in code which is now part of my question. Tried different inputs and seems to work .. Your inputs please .. do you think this will be accepted  in an interview ?

Comment: Your code will brick if you return -1 to access the array. It would be better to return a bool and the index in a reference variable